# Jquery if elemento (':visible')

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

Estou tentando criar um if para que se uma div estiver visível, outra desapareça (em um template wordpress):

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
       if($('.classe1').is(':visible'){
           $('.classe2').hide();
       }
});
```

Mas não está sendo reconhecido, o que posso fazer?

Comment: alguma mensagem de erro no console?

Comment: Votando para fechar como "erro de digitação" por causa da resposta.

Answer (score 2):

faltou o ultimo <kbd>)</kbd> no if `if($('.classe1').is(':visible')...`

```
$(document).ready(function($) { 
    if($('.classe1').is(':visible')) {
        $('.classe2').hide();
    }
});
```